# Is it possible to post system-wide messages in PHPBB3?

Tags: phpbb

Is it possible to post system-wide messages in PHPBB3?

I'm performing a server move today. The server has a pretty busy PHPBB3 forum on it.

I'm going to lock all forums during the DNS update.

I'd also like to post a system-wide message informing the forum-users about the server transfer.

What is the best way to accomplish this in PHPBB3?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You must allow the sending group permission to mass PM and you must allow the receiving group (registered users for all users) to receive mass PMs in Manage groups.

[From this post in PHPBB3 forum](http://www.phpbb.com/community/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=1196125)

Another option is to export all their email addresses and send out a newsletter to all of them letting them know of the upcoming updates and possible downtime

Answer (score 2):

There are some Annoucnment mods you can add.

If you use the Global post setting that will display your message on each forum topics page too.